# Older Stack Exchange podcasts aren't available any more

Tags: bug, status-completed, podcast

It looks like the files for several older episodes aren't available any more, for example [#13](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/se-podcast-13/) and [#12](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/se-podcast-12/):

> [image]

Following the download link ultimately redirects to [a dead archive.org page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130425203200/http://web.archive.org/web/http:/itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SE-StackExchange-2011.07.27.mp3).

Is there still a way to listen to these episodes?

Comment: I don't know anything about the older podtrac/ITC links, but the [Stack Exchange Soundcloud page](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange) has been rather drastically pruned. They could be re-arranging things, or perhaps someone forgot to pay the Soundcloud bill? "If you are over your limit, uploading more tracks will be disabled, and your oldest tracks may be hidden. Upgrade to display them and to be able to upload more."

Comment: The Soundcloud files have reappeared, so this no longer appears to be an issue, though the podtrac/ITC download links do seem to be outdated remnants of a bygone era.

Answer (score 7):

We did in fact forget to pay the SoundCloud bill at one point. (Or rather they caught on to just how much we were uploading and told us we had to *start* paying.)

Once we upgraded, all the old tracks came magically back. (This was six months ago, but I'm closing the loop on this post anyway.)

Comment: So they let you upload without a limit then keep the files hostage until you pay. So nice of them.

Comment: I don't think it was like that, @ShadowWizard. It was more that we'd been using them since before they had a free/paid tiers model, and when they introduced that we stayed in the free zone by default until some job got to our account and actually counted our uploaded minutes. More of an error than a crappy policy.

Comment: I see. Still not the best smell but I'll give them the benefit of the doubt. Glad it was all sorted out quickly, and hope it doesn't cost too much! :)